# Macbook air m1 достаточно ли 8gb оперативной?

Tags: ram, macbook

Ребята, подскажите
Буду благодарен
Я сейчас на пороге входа в разработку под IOS
Могу взять максимум mac air m1 8gb
Достаточно ли 8гб ОЗУ для разработки приложений на Swift?
Если есть личный опыт пользования прочими языками Python, C# на этом устройстве, скажите, это рабочая система для них?
Ещё раз, буду благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению 8 Gb очень мало, несмотря на то что она быстрая. Помимо своих обязанностей, из-за интегрированной видеокарты около 1.5Gb уходит на видеопоток, xcode вместе с chrome у меня довольно сильно лагает. Возможно лучше рассмотреть БУ варианты с 16 гигабайтами.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, поэтому дугие ответы не принимаются - пишу комментарий... У меня - наоборот, очень хорошие впечатления от эйра на m1. Очень быстрый запуск идеи, браузер с парой десятков вкладок и пара экземпляров VScode - и никакого торможения я не заметил. Правда, я не очень долго пользовался ноутом - мне его давали именно потестировать. Но я бы себе такой купил, и именно для разработки. Из недостатков - в форумах жалуются на недопиленность докера для арма, но эта проблема не имеет  отношения к памяти :-) и явно решится в скором будущем

Comment: @S.H. Если там стоит `SSD`, то в какой-то мере это может компенсировать недостаток памяти при работе с `IDE` и проектами. А то и быстрее будет, чем `HDD` с много памяти )